# GIT: Al modificar un archivo, pierde el ícono y el menú contextual

Tags: git

Tengo un archivo que inicia con el ícono de Normal (verde). Lo edito y le hago una modificación. El ícono del archivo no se actualiza por el de Modificado (rojo), queda sin ícono de GIT. La carpeta que lo contiene sí queda con el ícono rojo. Si pulso botón derecho sobre ese archivo, tampoco aparecen las opciones normales, como ver el log, o revertir o ver las diferencias. Sólo sucede para el archivo modificado, cómo si perdiera el vínculo. Si chequeo las diferencias a nivel de la carpeta contenedora detecta todo sin inconvenientes. Ya revisé el tema del registro pero no lo solucionó.

Comment: Git no incluye una interfaz gráfica de usuario ¿Cuál front-end para git usas?

Comment: Bienvenida, @MarcelaStifman! Suena a la extensión para Windows Explorer de Git for Windows. De pronto un screenshot ayudaría a entender lo que ves, y la salida por consola de `git status` (esto último **como texto**, no como imagen!).